# Reading address from form and outputting longitude & latitude

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-geocoder

I'm quite new to JavaScript and am currently playing around with it and practicing trying to get a Google-geocoder function to print out the longitude and latitude in text fields. I'm sure the code I have contains errors etc. Anyhow, the JS code I have (GeoCoder.js) looks like this:

```
function codeAddress()
{
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address  = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode( {'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        { 
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            document.getElementById("latitude").value = latitude;
            document.getElementById("longitude").value = longitude;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    }); 
}
```

I have also constructed a HTML file (Addresses.html), from which I expect to read an address and be able to output the longitude/latitude. My html file looks as follows:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="GeoCoder.js"></script>
</head>
<h2>Location</h2>
<form name="myform">
    <div>
        Address:<br>
        <input type="text" id="address" name="address">
        <input type="button" name="Click" id="firstButton" onclick="codeAddress()">
    </div>
    <div>
        Output:<br>
        <input type="text" id="longitude">
        <input type="text" id="latitude">
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm aware that what I have so far is incomplete, and does not function as it is supposed to. I'd like help with pointing out any errors, and in completing the task so that when I enter an address in the text field and push the button next to it, the longitude and latitude gets outputted in the output fields below the address.

Comment: First thing you should do is learn about debugging... Press F12 on your browser, and it should show some tools. Learning those will help you learn JavaScript on your own, just by allowing you to try things and see any errors that may arise.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Realized I wasn't using FireBug (obviously quite helpful for this), and as soon as I opened it I found my error blocking me from seeing my alerts. I forgot to include the script for googleapi.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this and tell me what is the result so that i can help you....

```
function codeAddress()
{
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address  = document.getElementById("address").value;
alert("address : "+address);// should display text you entered in input field
geocoder.geocode( {'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
{ 
alert("entered if statement");// you have entered if statement
var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
alert("latitude : "+latitude+" : longitude : "+longitude);// display values of latitude and longitude.
document.getElementById("latitude").value = latitude;
document.getElementById("longitude").value = longitude;
}
else
{
alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
}
}); 
}
```

if you get all alert message except the last one with correct values and still not able to set the values in input field try this...

```
document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML = latitude;
document.getElementById("longitude").innerHTML = longitude;
```

Comment: Got all the alerts to display. Now, if I wanted to output my longitude and latitude to the text fields I generated under "Output:" - how would I go about doing that?